# What could be wrong with this function?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I wrote the following to manually make changes to a button when clicked

```
const links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');


links.addEventListener('click', () => {
  links.classList.add('clickedLink');
})
```

..but the threw an error

> TypeError: links.addEventListener is not a function
> at /script.js:4:7'

..what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It says getElements,hence more elements,so you should run a loop for adding the event listeners on each element

```
for(let link of links){
link.addEventListener...
}
```